Solving Valueerror of Tooth segmentation model in machine learning for my graduation project please
Hi everyone, I'm having some issues with the code in classification.py from a model I got from here.
The program should offer the user two options:

Read and extract features from images: This option uses a FeatureExtraction module to extract 9 features (including the image name) from the images.
Read a pre-existing dataset: This option reads a dataset containing labels.csv, features.csv, and image files. It then asks the user for:

The number of times to execute the program (let's consider 5).
The desired number of folds for splitting the data using K-fold cross-validation (let's consider 5 folds, or k=5).
The size of the test dataset (let's consider 20%).



The model then passes these parameters to the classification function in the classification module. Here's where the issue arises:

The code passes the entire dataset to onlyfiles, which has 973 entries.
It then identifies images_name and label_color from labels.csv (which has 778 entries). This represents the training dataset, as we specified a 20% test set earlier (778 = 80% of 973).
The following for loop iterates through splits generated by k_folds.split(images_name). At this point, we're still dealing with the training dataset, and with k=5, there should be:

662 indices in train_index (for training data).
156 indices in test_index (for validation within the training set).



Here's where the error occurs in the next for loop:
for i in train_index:
    current_filename = onlyfiles[i].split('.')[0].strip()
    if current_filename in trainingDataset:
        # ... (rest of the code)
    else:
        print(f"Warning: '{current_filename}' not found in images_name because its index is {i}.train.")


The first line retrieves the filename (current_filename) based on its index i in train_index. Let's say i is 324, and train_index contains indices from 156 to 777 (while test_index ranges from 0 to 155).
The error occurs because sometimes the loop tries to find current_filename in images_name, but it's not present there. This is because images_name only has 778 entries (training data), and the remaining 195 entries (test data) are not included. So, current_filename might actually belong to the test dataset, causing the error "101_0032.JPG is not in the list."

I've tried sorting the lists and removing shuffling (set shuffle=False in k_folds.split), but the error persists. I would really appreciate some help in resolving this issue.
